# How to 'really' detect integers from DB?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to save some code with the following. I've an object with variables named the same as table rows so I could create an insert like this one:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table ";
        $columns = '(';
        $values = 'VALUES (';
        foreach ($this as $var => $value){
            if ($value){
                $columns .= $var.', ';
                if (!is_int($value))
                    $value = '\''.$value.'\'';
                $values .= $value.', ';
            }
        }
        $columns .= ')';
        $values .= ')';
        $columns = str_replace (', )', ')', $columns);
        $values = str_replace (', )', ')', $values);
        $query .= $columns." ".$values;
```

But every single variable is detected as string and that's not true in all fields as you may imagine.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Every single variable is detected as a string how so? If you're trying to insert strings (ie: text, longtext, varchar, etc) into non-string fields then your MySQL should be throwing an error.

Comment: In MySQL 5, if you wrap you integer with ' then it will still work and insert them as an integer.

Comment: What does $this contain in the above snippet?

Comment: Btw: `if (!is_int($value)) $value = '\''.$value.'\'';` would break if `$value` contains `'`

Comment: Can you post the definition of the class you're referring to with $this?

Comment: I don't think that your solution will be saving you any code in the long term.  It is wide open to SQL injection, and will make producing anything other than simple SQL statements very difficult.  You should really check out the documentation for [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or similar.

Comment: @VVS I could but it's just several variables. Why do you want to know that?

Comment: @Mike I'll escape them before doing that. It's obvious.

Comment: So, does the "int-variable" really have an int in it?

Comment: @VVS yes but the problem is that sometimes you may find numeric dates which arent strictly numeric, like ZIP Code.

Comment: @Antonio Laguna: In this case is_numeric() should be best suited for the situation.

Comment: Yeah, but what happens with a ZIP Code like 41907 (Spanish one) ?

Comment: How are we gonna be able to distinguish the zip code 41907 from the integer 41907 if they both are represented as "41907", is that your question?

Comment: Yeah, this is my question. Dates are rightfully set in Database but what happens to code?

Comment: If they are successfully inserted in the database they are stored as the specified datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would write it:

```
<?php
$canonical_columns = array_flip(array("column1", "column2", "column3"));
$columns = array_keys(array_intersect_key($canonical_columns, (array) $this));
$params = join(",", array_fill(0, count($columns), "?"));
$columns = join(",", $columns);
$query = "INSERT INTO table ($columns) VALUES ($params)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array_values($this));
```

Stop concatenating fragments of strings to form SQL.

Use PDO, and use parameters for values.

Allowlist column names by comparing inputs to known, valid column names.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, it's `array_keys()` and `array_values()`.  I'll update the code example above.  See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: And yes, I'm trying to use PHP builtin functions to better advantage, so we don't have to write so much code with `for` loops and meticulous `.=` string concatenation.

Comment: $this isn't supported as parameter to array_intersect but thanks for your support. Seems to be a really nice solution.

Comment: Yes, you may have to store your key/value pairs as an associative array, or find a way to convert your object's fields into an associative array.  E.g. `(array) $this` works (I tested it).

Comment: Okay this raises more questions than answers... I've tried with $columns = join(",", array_keys(array_intersect_key($canonical_columns, get_object_vars($this)))); . Although I've tried with 3 values, this is the $query INSERT INTO table (name,middlename,surname) VALUES (?)

Comment: My mistake.  We need to `count($columns)` while $columns is still an array.  Then join columns into a single string after that.  I have edited the above code.  I've also tested it on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you numbers are in fact strings. Try to use is_numeric() instead of is_int().
If this ain't enough you can cast the string to an integer and then check for != 0.

Comment: That would be fine but some data as ZIP Code is String and not number so if you try to convert it, it will success and then fail in the insert.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood your answer to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may insert numbers in quotes too, as strings. This will not create an error.